# MySQL - Querying for records created "today", but date is in UTC

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I currently store my datetimes in UTC, and for all purposes, it's worked fine so far. But now I want to query for records created on a particular day, like today, in my own timezone, which is Eastern.

Due to the difference in hours, records I'm creating at the moment will have tomorrow's date. For instance, the date portion would currently be `2016-06-20` in my timezone, but UTC is `2016-06-21`.

How could I accurately get records for a particular day in my own timezone when the records are stored as UTC? I was thinking that I could use the `convert_tz` function to convert the stored value to Eastern, and use that as part of my `where` clause. That way the dates match up. Is that a reliable solution?

Comment: You might visit your question history and start accepting answers if appropriate. It is not a promising sight for anyone that wants to answer one.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the datetime boundaries you are searching for into UTC.

The CONVERT_TZ function is convenient. Something like this:

```
WHERE my_utc_date_time_col >= CONVERT('2016-02-20','EST5EDT','+00:00') 
  AND my_utc_date_time_col <  CONVERT('2016-02-20','EST5EDT','+00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(This assumes that you've populated the MySQL time zone tables, so named time zones are supported.)

That winds up effectively equivalent to:

```
WHERE my_utc_date_time_col >= '2016-02-20' + INTERVAL 4 HOUR
  AND my_utc_date_time_col <  '2016-02-20' + INTERVAL 4 HOUR + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

or

```
WHERE my_utc_date_time_col >= '2016-02-20 04:00:00'
  AND my_utc_date_time_col <  '2016-02-21 04:00:00'
```

If you want to reference a function such as `NOW()` to get the current date, then the timezone of the MySQL connection is going to be important, because the datetime value returned will be in the time_zone of the MySQL connection.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone' ;
```

Note that we prefer to do the conversion on the *literal* side rather than on the column, because if we do it on the column, that forces MySQL to perform the conversion for *every* row in the table, and compare the literal. When we do the conversion on the literal side, that allows MySQL to make effective use an index range scan operation (with an appropriate index available.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've done something similar to what you mentioned, and so I do the conversion on the literal side and compare that against the columns.

Answer (score 1):

The [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function is in fact what you need. But I disagree with:

> I could use the convert_tz function to convert the stored value to
>   Eastern, and use that as part of my where clause.

Because using functions on the `WHERE` clause **might** reduce performance.

If you're using stored procedures, I suggest that you convert first the input dates, then use them in your `SELECT` statement. It would look something like this:

```
SET @fromDate = CONVERT_TZ(@fromDate, ...) --Convert to UTC
SET @toDate = CONVERT_TZ(@toDate, ...) --Convert to UTC

SELECT *
    FROM TableA A
    WHERE A.FromDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
$foo = new DateTime("today", new DateTimeZone("America/Vancouver"));
var_dump($foo->format('c'), $foo->format('U'));
$foo->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
var_dump($foo->format('c'), $foo->format('U'), $foo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Output:

```
string(25) "2016-06-20T00:00:00-07:00"
string(10) "1466406000"
string(25) "2016-06-20T07:00:00+00:00"
string(10) "1466406000"
string(19) "2016-06-20 07:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html

```sql
    SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'America/Vancouver')) as VancouverToday;
```

I'm not saying this is optimized, fast, etc. I'm just saying if you've stored UTC values and/or your server is UTC and you're looking for a comparison for Today, this shows you "today" adjusted for your timezone.